# R Programming - List Conversion

Tags: r, list

I have a list like so:

```
head(myList)
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"  

[[2]]
[1] "c" "d"

[[3]]
[1] "e"  "f"
```

My desired output is a dataframe:

```
col1   col2
a      b
c      d
e      f
```

How can I do this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `do.call(rbind, mylist)` or `as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, mylist))` if you want a data frame instead of a matrix

Comment: @nicola - Sorry, did not read the question carefully enough...

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
a<-list(c("a", "b"), c("c", "d"), c("e", "f"))
t(data.frame(a))
```

Cheerio.

UPDATE:

```
data.frame(t(data.frame(a, row.names=c("col1", "col2"))), row.names=1:length(a))
#   col1 col2
# 1    a    b
# 2    c    d
# 3    e    f
```

UPDATE 2:

Here's another version.

```
data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(a), 2, 3, dimnames=list(c("col1", "col2"), 1:length(a)))))
```

which fixes the formatting and the ugliness.

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach is `do.call(rbind, a)`, as mentioned by @DavidArenburg. But, as with many things R, there are alternatives.

Here are two:

In base R, you can use `simplify2array` (but it's been known to be slow).

```
t(simplify2array(a))
```

You can also use `sti_list2matrix`, which is used for similar purposes as `simplify2array` but is much faster and doesn't require transposing:

```
library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(a, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "a"  "b" 
# [2,] "c"  "d" 
# [3,] "e"  "f"
```

Combining that with some `dimnames<-` trickery, you can get to your desired `data.frame` quite easily.

```
as.data.frame(`dimnames<-`(stri_list2matrix(a, byrow = TRUE), 
                           list(NULL, c("col1", "col2"))))
#   col1 col2
# 1    a    b
# 2    c    d
# 3    e    f
```

Comment: `setNames(data.frame(stri_list2matrix(a, byrow = TRUE)),c("col1","col2"))` might be more straight-forward than calling `dimnames<-`